# sql Query SyntaxError on flask

Tags: python, sql, flask

```
average=db.execute("SELECT AVG(rate) FROM review JOIN book ON review.bid = book.id WHERE isbn= :isbn ", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchone()
```

syntax error is given when run it would you please help me

Comment: What is the syntax error you're receiving?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: when I use AVG function it gives this error

Comment: you are using an aggregation function with precise filter on only one isbn... this is weird and sign of a probable misunderstanding. aggregation functions are usually used with a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: @Mustafa . . . The query looks fine.  You don't need a `GROUP BY`.